# New to Laravel, why is $car not getting passed to my search view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I dd($car) in my search page, it shows up as this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GduO7.png)

Route:

```
Route::get('/search', [RepairController::class, 'search']);
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Car $car, Repair $repairs)
    {
        $repairs_new = DB::table('repairs')->where('car_id', '=', $car->id)->get();

        return view('cars.search',
            [   'car' => $car,
                'repairs_new' => $repairs_new]
        );
    }
```

If you need any additional information to solve this let me know in the comments, thank you.

EDIT (more code + changes):

Search form:

```
<form class="form-inline" type="get" action="/search/{car}">
  <input
    class="form-control shadow appearance-none border rounded w-100 py-2 px-3 mb-2 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
    type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search repairs">
  <button
    class="w-32 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold p-2 m-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
    type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The route:

```
 Route::get('/search/{car}', [RepairController::class, 'search']);
```

The search function in controller:

```
public function search(Car $car, Repair $repairs)
    {
        $search_text = $_GET['query'];
        // $repairs = $car->repairs()->get();
        // $repairs_new = $repairs->where($repairs->car_id, '=', $car->id)->get();
        $repairs_new = $repairs->where('repair', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_text . '%')->where('car_id', 'LIKE', $car->id)->get();
        // $repairs_new = DB::table('repairs')->where('car_id', '=', $car->id)->get();

        return view('cars.search',
            [   'car' => $car,
                'repairs_new' => $repairs_new]
        );
    }
```

Comment: `action="/search/{car}"` you seem to be confusing URLs and route definitions, and `type="get"` is not a valid form attribute. Where is `$repairs` coming from in your controller?

Comment: Yes, most of the problem was due to this confusion, I got it fixed in the end :D Thanks for the help, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name), you need to specify how you retrieve the information in the route.

```
Route::get('/search/{car:id?}/{repairs:id?}', [RepairController::class, 'search']);
```

Where `:id` is the database column used to do the lookup. So in this case you'd visit `/search/1/1` where `1` is the `id` for the `Car` and `Repairs` record.

> Note: `?` at the end of the slug is [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) here.

Not entirely sure why you're using the `DB` facade when you can easily [use relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) here and do something as simple as `$car->repairs()` to get the Repairs and just simply pass in the `Car` model to the search.

Comment: `id` is not needed here as it's the default key for the model.

Comment: Correct it isn't, but it shows the concept of slugs (for pretty URL rather than `search/1/1/`) and I didn't want to assume any other columns the OP hasn't mentioned. @miken32

Comment: Ok, but do keep in mind that specifying the key changes the behaviour of the model binding: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping

Comment: Don't think I've ever actually looked that far into the docs, pretty cool to see relationships can be utilised, or "assumed" with implicit binding. The OP doesn't use them unfortunately but would probably be a perfect use-case here if they did. @miken32

Comment: The problem I'm now facing is the URL looking like this after entering New in the search field and pressing the search button:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/%7Bcar%7D?query=New

I'll edit the main post so you can see what code changes I did

Comment: Then control the URL in the way your controller can interpret it. What exactly are you doing here? Read the documentation as already suggested.

Comment: Another small thing, chaining optional URL params can cause issues; if you had the route: `search/2`, where 2 was the ID of the Repair, your code would still think 2 is the ID of the Car; it doesn't know how to skip `/{car}` unless you did `/search/null/2`, or `search/0/2`. In this case, I would suggest either A) not having `/{car}` as optional, or B) using `/search` and Query String params: `?car=1&repair=2`. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I feel extremely stupid that this took me like 3 hours to fix, but I finally understood what I was doing wrong and got the code working properly :D